# Jquery .after not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, html

I've basically got a normal table with dynamic data going into it. For styling purposes i am inserting table headers below each tr so i can get the effect of a double border on my tables. This it a little bad from a semantics point of view i think, but it was the only way i got the effect to work as i wanted. My tr's have a border top, but border bottom doesn't show because i need `border-collapse: collapse;` on my table. So my idea was so insert something after each tr that i could apply a border or background colour to in order to achieve the desired look i want.

My problem now is that in IE the .after doesn't seem to be inserting the extra th therefore im not getting my double border.

Firstly i there a better way to get the effect i want and secondly why is the .after not working IE?

This is my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.details tr, .detailsinner tr').after('<th class="line" colspan="2"></th>');
});
```

Regards
M

Comment: I think the problem is that IE is inserting it, but because it is invalid it's not displaying it.

Comment: .after is working on IE.. Check your code if u miss something or miss spell something..

Comment: $('.details tr, .detailsinner tr').after(function() {
  return '<th class="line" colspan="2"></th>';
});                 /// try to give like this;;

Comment: @Learner I should have seen it earlier that he just had to wrap the `<th>...</th>` inside `<tr>` tags :(